# React-Native xcodebuild error 65 when building iOS Expo app

Tags: react-native, expo, cocoapods

I'm attempting to build an existing React-Native project in iOS. This project uses Expo, so after running `yarn`, I run `npx expo prebuild`. Then I run `expo run:ios` and get the following output. I've tried cleaning and reinstalling the pod directly in the `/ios` folder, changing node versions, and removing `Podfile.lock`.

✅ Compilation Logs:

```
❯ yarn ios
yarn run v1.22.19
$ expo run:ios
✔ Created native project | gitignore skipped
› Metro skipped: Project metro.config.js does not match prebuild template.
› Ensure the project uses expo/metro-config.
  Learn more
✔ Updated package.json and added index.js entry point for iOS and Android
› Installing using yarn
> yarn install
✔ Config synced
✔ Installed pods and initialized Xcode workspace.
› Signing and building iOS app with: Apple Development: myemail@example.com (MY_APPLE_ID)
› Planning build
› Preparing Pods/expo-dev-menu-EXDevMenu » ResourceBundle-EXDevMenu-expo-dev-menu-Info.plist
› Preparing react-native Pods/React-Core-AccessibilityResources » ResourceBundle-AccessibilityResources-React-Core-Info.plist
› Preparing Pods/expo-dev-launcher-EXDevLauncher » ResourceBundle-EXDevLauncher-expo-dev-launcher-Info.plist
› Preparing Pods/RNImageCropPicker-QBImagePicker » ResourceBundle-QBImagePicker-RNImageCropPicker-Info.plist
› Preparing expo-updates Pods/EXUpdates-EXUpdates » ResourceBundle-EXUpdates-EXUpdates-Info.plist
› Preparing expo-constants Pods/EXConstants-EXConstants » ResourceBundle-EXConstants-EXConstants-Info.plist
› Copying   TOCropViewController/TOCropViewControllerBundle.bundle/Base.lproj ➜ ios/Pods/TOCropViewController/Objective-C/TOCropViewController/Resources/Base.lproj
› Preparing Pods/TOCropViewController-TOCropViewControllerBundle » ResourceBundle-TOCropViewControllerBundle-TOCropViewController-Info.plist
› Copying   TOCropViewController/TOCropViewControllerBundle.bundle/zh-Hant.lproj ➜ ios/Pods/TOCropViewController/Objective-C/TOCropViewController/Resources/zh-Hant.lproj
› Copying   TOCropViewController/TOCropViewControllerBundle.bundle/zh-Hans.lproj ➜ ios/Pods/TOCropViewController/Objective-C/TOCropViewController/Resources/zh-Hans.lproj
› Copying   TOCropViewController/TOCropViewControllerBundle.bundle/vi.lproj ➜ ios/Pods/TOCropViewController/Objective-C/TOCropViewController/Resources/vi.lproj
› Copying   TOCropViewController/TOCropViewControllerBundle.bundle/ru.lproj ➜ ios/Pods/TOCropViewController/Objective-C/TOCropViewController/Resources/ru.lproj
› Copying   TOCropViewController/TOCropViewControllerBundle.bundle/tr.lproj ➜ ios/Pods/TOCropViewController/Objective-C/TOCropViewController/Resources/tr.lproj
› Copying   TOCropViewController/TOCropViewControllerBundle.bundle/ro.lproj ➜ ios/Pods/TOCropViewController/Objective-C/TOCropViewController/Resources/ro.lproj
› Copying   TOCropViewController/TOCropViewControllerBundle.bundle/sk.lproj ➜ ios/Pods/TOCropViewController/Objective-C/TOCropViewController/Resources/sk.lproj
› Copying   TOCropViewController/TOCropViewControllerBundle.bundle/pt.lproj ➜ ios/Pods/TOCropViewController/Objective-C/TOCropViewController/Resources/pt.lproj
› Executing react-native Pods/hermes-engine » [CP] Copy XCFrameworks
› Copying   TOCropViewController/TOCropViewControllerBundle.bundle/pt-BR.lproj ➜ ios/Pods/TOCropViewController/Objective-C/TOCropViewController/Resources/pt-BR.lproj
› Copying   TOCropViewController/TOCropViewControllerBundle.bundle/pl.lproj ➜ ios/Pods/TOCropViewController/Objective-C/TOCropViewController/Resources/pl.lproj
› Copying   TOCropViewController/TOCropViewControllerBundle.bundle/nl.lproj ➜ ios/Pods/TOCropViewController/Objective-C/TOCropViewController/Resources/nl.lproj
› Copying   TOCropViewController/TOCropViewControllerBundle.bundle/ms.lproj ➜ ios/Pods/TOCropViewController/Objective-C/TOCropViewController/Resources/ms.lproj
› Copying   TOCropViewController/TOCropViewControllerBundle.bundle/ko.lproj ➜ ios/Pods/TOCropViewController/Objective-C/TOCropViewController/Resources/ko.lproj
› Copying   TOCropViewController/TOCropViewControllerBundle.bundle/ja.lproj ➜ ios/Pods/TOCropViewController/Objective-C/TOCropViewController/Resources/ja.lproj
› Copying   TOCropViewController/TOCropViewControllerBundle.bundle/it.lproj ➜ ios/Pods/TOCropViewController/Objective-C/TOCropViewController/Resources/it.lproj
› Copying   TOCropViewController/TOCropViewControllerBundle.bundle/id.lproj ➜ ios/Pods/TOCropViewController/Objective-C/TOCropViewController/Resources/id.lproj
› Copying   TOCropViewController/TOCropViewControllerBundle.bundle/hu.lproj ➜ ios/Pods/TOCropViewController/Objective-C/TOCropViewController/Resources/hu.lproj
› Copying   TOCropViewController/TOCropViewControllerBundle.bundle/fr.lproj ➜ ios/Pods/TOCropViewController/Objective-C/TOCropViewController/Resources/fr.lproj
› Copying   TOCropViewController/TOCropViewControllerBundle.bundle/fi.lproj ➜ ios/Pods/TOCropViewController/Objective-C/TOCropViewController/Resources/fi.lproj
› Copying   TOCropViewController/TOCropViewControllerBundle.bundle/fa.lproj ➜ ios/Pods/TOCropViewController/Objective-C/TOCropViewController/Resources/fa.lproj
› Copying   TOCropViewController/TOCropViewControllerBundle.bundle/fa-IR.lproj ➜ ios/Pods/TOCropViewController/Objective-C/TOCropViewController/Resources/fa-IR.lproj
› Copying   TOCropViewController/TOCropViewControllerBundle.bundle/es.lproj ➜ ios/Pods/TOCropViewController/Objective-C/TOCropViewController/Resources/es.lproj
› Copying   TOCropViewController/TOCropViewControllerBundle.bundle/en.lproj ➜ ios/Pods/TOCropViewController/Objective-C/TOCropViewController/Resources/en.lproj
› Copying   TOCropViewController/TOCropViewControllerBundle.bundle/de.lproj ➜ ios/Pods/TOCropViewController/Objective-C/TOCropViewController/Resources/de.lproj
› Copying   TOCropViewController/TOCropViewControllerBundle.bundle/da-DK.lproj ➜ ios/Pods/TOCropViewController/Objective-C/TOCropViewController/Resources/da-DK.lproj
› Copying   TOCropViewController/TOCropViewControllerBundle.bundle/ca.lproj ➜ ios/Pods/TOCropViewController/Objective-C/TOCropViewController/Resources/ca.lproj
› Copying   TOCropViewController/TOCropViewControllerBundle.bundle/cs.lproj ➜ ios/Pods/TOCropViewController/Objective-C/TOCropViewController/Resources/cs.lproj
› Copying   TOCropViewController/TOCropViewControllerBundle.bundle/ar.lproj ➜ ios/Pods/TOCropViewController/Objective-C/TOCropViewController/Resources/ar.lproj
› Compiling expo-image Pods/libaom » wedge_utils.c
› Compiling expo-image Pods/libaom » yv12config.c
› Compiling expo-image Pods/libaom » yv12extend.c
› Compiling expo-image Pods/libaom » vmaf.c
› Compiling expo-image Pods/libaom » warped_motion.c
› Compiling expo-image Pods/libaom » variance.c
--- expo-image COMPILATION LOGS CONT ---
› Compiling react-native Pods/libevent » strlcpy.c
› Compiling react-native Pods/libevent » signal.c
› Compiling react-native Pods/libevent » select.c
› Compiling react-native Pods/libevent » poll.c
› Compiling react-native Pods/libevent » log.c
› Compiling react-native Pods/libevent » listener.c
› Compiling react-native Pods/libevent » libevent-dummy.m
› Compiling react-native Pods/libevent » kqueue.c
› Compiling react-native Pods/libevent » http.c
› Compiling react-native Pods/libevent » evutil_time.c
› Compiling react-native Pods/libevent » evutil_rand.c
› Compiling react-native Pods/libevent » evutil.c
› Compiling react-native Pods/libevent » evthread.c
› Compiling react-native Pods/libevent » evrpc.c
› Compiling react-native Pods/libevent » evmap.c
› Compiling react-native Pods/libevent » event_tagging.c
› Compiling react-native Pods/libevent » event.c
› Compiling react-native Pods/libevent » evdns.c
› Compiling react-native Pods/libevent » bufferevent_sock.c
› Compiling react-native Pods/libevent » bufferevent_ratelim.c
› Compiling react-native Pods/libevent » bufferevent_pair.c
› Compiling react-native Pods/libevent » bufferevent_filter.c
› Compiling react-native Pods/libevent » bufferevent.c
› Compiling react-native Pods/libevent » buffer.c
› Compiling expo-image Pods/libavif » write.c
› Compiling expo-image Pods/libavif » utils.c
› Compiling expo-image Pods/libavif » stream.c
-- expo-image COMPILATION LOGS CONT ---
› Compiling react-native Pods/glog » vlog_is_on.cc
› Compiling react-native Pods/glog » utilities.cc
› Compiling react-native Pods/glog » symbolize.cc
› Compiling rn-fetch-blob Pods/rn-fetch-blob » rn-fetch-blob-dummy.m
› Compiling rn-fetch-blob Pods/rn-fetch-blob » RNFetchBlobRequest.m
› Compiling rn-fetch-blob Pods/rn-fetch-blob » RNFetchBlobFS.m
› Compiling rn-fetch-blob Pods/rn-fetch-blob » RNFetchBlobConst.m
› Compiling rn-fetch-blob Pods/rn-fetch-blob » RNFetchBlob.m
› Compiling react-native-splash-screen Pods/react-native-splash-screen » react-native-splash-screen-dummy.m
› Compiling react-native-splash-screen Pods/react-native-splash-screen » RNSplashScreen.m
› Compiling react-native-safe-area-context Pods/react-native-safe-area-context » react-native-safe-area-context-dummy.m
› Compiling react-native-safe-area-context Pods/react-native-safe-area-context » RNCSafeAreaViewMode.m
› Compiling react-native-pager-view Pods/react-native-pager-view » UIViewController+CreateExtension.m
› Compiling react-native-pager-view Pods/react-native-pager-view » ReactViewPagerManager.m
› Compiling react-native Pods/glog » signalhandler.cc
› Compiling react-native Pods/glog » raw_logging.cc
› Compiling react-native-image-crop-picker Pods/TOCropViewController » UIImage+CropRotate.m
› Compiling react-native-image-crop-picker Pods/TOCropViewController » TOCroppedImageAttributes.m
› Compiling react-native-image-crop-picker Pods/TOCropViewController » TOCropViewControllerTransitioning.m
› Compiling react-native-image-crop-picker Pods/TOCropViewController » TOCropViewController.m
› Compiling react-native-image-crop-picker Pods/TOCropViewController » TOCropViewController-dummy.m
› Compiling react-native-image-crop-picker Pods/TOCropViewController » TOCropView.m
› Compiling react-native-image-crop-picker Pods/TOCropViewController » TOCropToolbar.m
› Compiling react-native-image-crop-picker Pods/TOCropViewController » TOCropScrollView.m
› Compiling react-native-image-crop-picker Pods/TOCropViewController » TOCropOverlayView.m
› Compiling react-native-image-crop-picker Pods/TOCropViewController » TOActivityCroppedImageProvider.m
› Packaging react-native Pods/Yoga » libYoga.a
› Compiling Pods/Sentry » fishhook.c
› Compiling Pods/Sentry » UIViewController+Sentry.m
› Compiling Pods/Sentry » UIView+Sentry.m
› Compiling Pods/Sentry » SentryViewHierarchyIntegration.m
› Compiling Pods/Sentry » SentryViewHierarchy.m
› Compiling Pods/Sentry » SentryUserFeedback.m
› Compiling Pods/Sentry » SentryUser.m
› Compiling Pods/Sentry » SentryUIViewControllerSwizzling.m
› Packaging react-native-image-crop-picker Pods/TOCropViewController » libTOCropViewController.a
--- Pods/Sentry COMPILATION LOGS CONT ---
› Packaging Pods/Sentry » libSentry.a
```

❌ Error Logs:

```
› Compiling expo-image Pods/SDWebImageAVIFCoder » Conversion.m
❌  (/my-app/ios/Pods/SDWebImageAVIFCoder/SDWebImageAVIFCoder/Classes/Conversion.m:158:28)

  156 |     state->biasY = (state->yuvRange == AVIF_RANGE_LIMITED) ? (float)(16 << (state->yuvDepth - 8)) : 0.0f;
  157 |     state->biasUV = (float)(1 << (state->yuvDepth - 1));
> 158 |     state->biasA = (image->alphaRange == AVIF_RANGE_LIMITED) ? (float)(16 << (state->yuvDepth - 8)) : 0.0f;
      |                            ^ no member named 'alphaRange' in 'struct avifImage'; did you mean 'alphaPlane'?
  159 |     state->rangeY = (float)((state->yuvRange == AVIF_RANGE_LIMITED) ? (219 << (state->yuvDepth - 8)) : state->yuvMaxChannel);
  160 |     state->rangeUV = (float)((state->yuvRange == AVIF_RANGE_LIMITED) ? (224 << (state->yuvDepth - 8)) : state->yuvMaxChannel);
  161 |     state->rangeA = (float)((image->alphaRange == AVIF_RANGE_LIMITED) ? (219 << (state->yuvDepth - 8)) : state->yuvMaxChannel);


❌  (/my-app/ios/Pods/SDWebImageAVIFCoder/SDWebImageAVIFCoder/Classes/Conversion.m:158:12)

  156 |     state->biasY = (state->yuvRange == AVIF_RANGE_LIMITED) ? (float)(16 << (state->yuvDepth - 8)) : 0.0f;
  157 |     state->biasUV = (float)(1 << (state->yuvDepth - 1));
> 158 |     state->biasA = (image->alphaRange == AVIF_RANGE_LIMITED) ? (float)(16 << (state->yuvDepth - 8)) : 0.0f;
      |            ^ no member named 'biasA' in 'struct avifReformatState'; did you mean 'biasY'?
  159 |     state->rangeY = (float)((state->yuvRange == AVIF_RANGE_LIMITED) ? (219 << (state->yuvDepth - 8)) : state->yuvMaxChannel);
  160 |     state->rangeUV = (float)((state->yuvRange == AVIF_RANGE_LIMITED) ? (224 << (state->yuvDepth - 8)) : state->yuvMaxChannel);
  161 |     state->rangeA = (float)((image->alphaRange == AVIF_RANGE_LIMITED) ? (219 << (state->yuvDepth - 8)) : state->yuvMaxChannel);


❌  (/my-app/ios/Pods/SDWebImageAVIFCoder/SDWebImageAVIFCoder/Classes/Conversion.m:161:37)

  159 |     state->rangeY = (float)((state->yuvRange == AVIF_RANGE_LIMITED) ? (219 << (state->yuvDepth - 8)) : state->yuvMaxChannel);
  160 |     state->rangeUV = (float)((state->yuvRange == AVIF_RANGE_LIMITED) ? (224 << (state->yuvDepth - 8)) : state->yuvMaxChannel);
> 161 |     state->rangeA = (float)((image->alphaRange == AVIF_RANGE_LIMITED) ? (219 << (state->yuvDepth - 8)) : state->yuvMaxChannel);
      |                                     ^ no member named 'alphaRange' in 'struct avifImage'; did you mean 'alphaPlane'?
  162 | 
  163 |     uint32_t cpCount = 1 << image->depth;
  164 |     if (state->mode == AVIF_REFORMAT_MODE_IDENTITY) {


❌  (/my-app/ios/Pods/SDWebImageAVIFCoder/SDWebImageAVIFCoder/Classes/Conversion.m:161:12)

  159 |     state->rangeY = (float)((state->yuvRange == AVIF_RANGE_LIMITED) ? (219 << (state->yuvDepth - 8)) : state->yuvMaxChannel);
  160 |     state->rangeUV = (float)((state->yuvRange == AVIF_RANGE_LIMITED) ? (224 << (state->yuvDepth - 8)) : state->yuvMaxChannel);
> 161 |     state->rangeA = (float)((image->alphaRange == AVIF_RANGE_LIMITED) ? (219 << (state->yuvDepth - 8)) : state->yuvMaxChannel);
      |            ^ no member named 'rangeA' in 'struct avifReformatState'; did you mean 'rangeY'?
  162 | 
  163 |     uint32_t cpCount = 1 << image->depth;
  164 |     if (state->mode == AVIF_REFORMAT_MODE_IDENTITY) {


❌  (/my-app/ios/Pods/SDWebImageAVIFCoder/SDWebImageAVIFCoder/Classes/Conversion.m:570:18)

  568 |     if(hasAlpha) { // alpha
  569 |         vImage_Buffer alphaBuffer = {0};
> 570 |         if(avif->alphaRange == AVIF_RANGE_LIMITED) {
      |                  ^ no member named 'alphaRange' in 'struct avifImage'; did you mean 'alphaPlane'?
  571 |             float* floatAlphaBufferData = NULL;
  572 |             floatAlphaBufferData = calloc(avif->width * avif->height, sizeof(float));
  573 |             scaledAlphaBufferData = calloc(avif->width * avif->height, sizeof(uint8_t));


❌  (/my-app/ios/Pods/SDWebImageAVIFCoder/SDWebImageAVIFCoder/Classes/Conversion.m:865:22)

  863 |         float rangeMax = 0.0f;
  864 |         if(avif->depth == 10) {
> 865 |             if(avif->alphaRange == AVIF_RANGE_LIMITED) {
      |                      ^ no member named 'alphaRange' in 'struct avifImage'; did you mean 'alphaPlane'?
  866 |                 offset = 64.0f;
  867 |                 rangeMax = 940.0f;
  868 |             } else {


❌  (/my-app/ios/Pods/SDWebImageAVIFCoder/SDWebImageAVIFCoder/Classes/Conversion.m:873:22)

  871 |             }
  872 |         } else if(avif->depth == 12) {
> 873 |             if(avif->alphaRange == AVIF_RANGE_LIMITED) {
      |                      ^ no member named 'alphaRange' in 'struct avifImage'; did you mean 'alphaPlane'?
  874 |                 offset = 256.0f;
  875 |                 rangeMax = 3760.0f;
  876 |             } else {

› Compiling expo-image Pods/SDWebImageAVIFCoder » ColorSpace.m
› Compiling expo-image Pods/SDWebImage » UIView+WebCacheOperation.m
› Compiling expo-image Pods/SDWebImage » UIView+WebCache.m
› Compiling expo-image Pods/SDWebImage » UIImageView+WebCache.m
› Compiling expo-image Pods/SDWebImage » UIImageView+HighlightedWebCache.m
› Compiling expo-image Pods/SDWebImage » UIImage+Transform.m
› Compiling expo-image Pods/SDWebImage » UIImage+MultiFormat.m
› Compiling expo-image Pods/SDWebImage » UIImage+Metadata.m
```

⚠️ Warnings:

```
    Run script build phase '[CP-User] Generate app.manifest for expo-updates' will be run during every build because it does not specify any outputs. To address this warning, either add output dependencies to the script phase, or configure it to run in every build by unchecking "Based on dependency analysis" in the script phase. (in target 'EXUpdates' from project 'Pods')
    Run script build phase 'Start Packager' will be run during every build because it does not specify any outputs. To address this warning, either add output dependencies to the script phase, or configure it to run in every build by unchecking "Based on dependency analysis" in the script phase. (in target 'MyApp' from project 'MyApp')
    Run script build phase 'Bundle React Native code and images' will be run during every build because it does not specify any outputs. To address this warning, either add output dependencies to the script phase, or configure it to run in every build by unchecking "Based on dependency analysis" in the script phase. (in target 'MyApp' from project 'MyApp')
    Run script build phase 'Upload Debug Symbols to Sentry' will be run during every build because it does not specify any outputs. To address this warning, either add output dependencies to the script phase, or configure it to run in every build by unchecking "Based on dependency analysis" in the script phase. (in target 'MyApp' from project 'MyApp')
    Run script build phase '[CP-User] Generate app.config for prebuilt Constants.manifest' will be run during every build because it does not specify any outputs. To address this warning, either add output dependencies to the script phase, or configure it to run in every build by unchecking "Based on dependency analysis" in the script phase. (in target 'EXConstants' from project 'Pods')

› 7 error(s), and 5 warning(s)

CommandError: Failed to build iOS project. "xcodebuild" exited with error code 65.
error Command failed with exit code 1.
```

`package.json`

```
"scripts": {
    "postinstall": "patch-package",
    "prebuild": "expo prebuild",
    "android": "expo run:android",
    "ios": "expo run:ios",
    "web": "expo start --web",
    "build-web": "expo export:web && node ./scripts/post-web-build.js && cp --verbose ./web-build/static/js/*.* ./bskyweb/static/js/",
    "start": "expo start --dev-client",
    "clean-cache": "rm -rf node_modules/.cache/babel-loader/*",
    "test": "jest --forceExit --testTimeout=20000 --bail",
    "test-watch": "jest --watchAll",
    "test-ci": "jest --ci --forceExit --reporters=default --reporters=jest-junit",
    "test-coverage": "jest --coverage",
    "lint": "eslint ./src --ext .js,.jsx,.ts,.tsx",
    "e2e:mock-server": "ts-node __e2e__/mock-server.ts",
    "e2e:metro": "RN_SRC_EXT=e2e.ts,e2e.tsx expo run:ios",
    "e2e:build": "detox build -c ios.sim.debug",
    "e2e:run": "detox test --configuration ios.sim.debug --take-screenshots all"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@atproto/api": "0.3.3",
    "@bam.tech/react-native-image-resizer": "^3.0.4",
    "@braintree/sanitize-url": "^6.0.2",
    "@expo/webpack-config": "^18.0.1",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^6.1.1",
    "@fortawesome/free-regular-svg-icons": "^6.1.1",
    "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^6.1.1",
    "@fortawesome/react-native-fontawesome": "^0.3.0",
    "@gorhom/bottom-sheet": "^4",
    "@mattermost/react-native-paste-input": "^0.6.0",
    "@miblanchard/react-native-slider": "^2.2.0",
    "@notifee/react-native": "^7.4.0",
    "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "^1.17.6",
    "@react-native-camera-roll/camera-roll": "^5.2.2",
    "@react-native-clipboard/clipboard": "^1.10.0",
    "@react-native-community/blur": "^4.3.0",
    "@react-native-community/datetimepicker": "6.7.3",
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^6.5.7",
    "@react-navigation/drawer": "^6.6.2",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.1.6",
    "@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.9.12",
    "@segment/analytics-next": "^1.51.3",
    "@segment/analytics-react": "^1.0.0-rc1",
    "@segment/analytics-react-native": "^2.10.1",
    "@segment/sovran-react-native": "^0.4.5",
    "@sentry/react-native": "4.13.0",
    "@tiptap/core": "^2.0.0-beta.220",
    "@tiptap/extension-document": "^2.0.0-beta.220",
    "@tiptap/extension-hard-break": "^2.0.3",
    "@tiptap/extension-history": "^2.0.3",
    "@tiptap/extension-link": "^2.0.0-beta.220",
    "@tiptap/extension-mention": "^2.0.0-beta.220",
    "@tiptap/extension-paragraph": "^2.0.0-beta.220",
    "@tiptap/extension-placeholder": "^2.0.0-beta.220",
    "@tiptap/extension-text": "^2.0.0-beta.220",
    "@tiptap/pm": "^2.0.0-beta.220",
    "@tiptap/react": "^2.0.0-beta.220",
    "@tiptap/suggestion": "^2.0.0-beta.220",
    "@types/node": "^18.16.2",
    "@zxing/text-encoding": "^0.9.0",
    "await-lock": "^2.2.2",
    "base64-js": "^1.5.1",
    "email-validator": "^2.0.4",
    "eslint-plugin-react-native-a11y": "^3.3.0",
    "expo": "~48.0.15",
    "expo-application": "~5.1.1",
    "expo-build-properties": "~0.5.1",
    "expo-camera": "~13.2.1",
    "expo-constants": "~14.2.1",
    "expo-dev-client": "~2.1.1",
    "expo-device": "~5.2.1",
    "expo-image": "^1.2.1",
    "expo-image-manipulator": "^11.1.1",
    "expo-image-picker": "^14.1.1",
    "expo-localization": "~14.1.1",
    "expo-media-library": "~15.2.3",
    "expo-sharing": "~11.2.2",
    "expo-splash-screen": "~0.18.2",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.4.4",
    "expo-system-ui": "~2.2.1",
    "expo-updates": "~0.16.4",
    "fast-text-encoding": "^1.0.6",
    "graphemer": "^1.4.0",
    "he": "^1.2.0",
    "history": "^5.3.0",
    "js-sha256": "^0.9.0",
    "lande": "^1.0.10",
    "lodash.chunk": "^4.2.0",
    "lodash.clonedeep": "^4.5.0",
    "lodash.debounce": "^4.0.8",
    "lodash.isequal": "^4.5.0",
    "lodash.omit": "^4.5.0",
    "lodash.samplesize": "^4.2.0",
    "lodash.set": "^4.3.2",
    "lodash.shuffle": "^4.2.0",
    "lru_map": "^0.4.1",
    "mobx": "^6.6.1",
    "mobx-react-lite": "^3.4.0",
    "mobx-utils": "^6.0.6",
    "normalize-url": "^8.0.0",
    "patch-package": "^6.5.1",
    "postinstall-postinstall": "^2.1.0",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-avatar-editor": "^13.0.0",
    "react-circular-progressbar": "^2.1.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-native": "0.71.7",
    "react-native-appstate-hook": "^1.0.6",
    "react-native-background-fetch": "^4.1.8",
    "react-native-drawer-layout": "^3.2.0",
    "react-native-fs": "^2.20.0",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~2.9.0",
    "react-native-get-random-values": "^1.8.0",
    "react-native-haptic-feedback": "^1.14.0",
    "react-native-image-crop-picker": "^0.38.1",
    "react-native-inappbrowser-reborn": "^3.6.3",
    "react-native-linear-gradient": "^2.6.2",
    "react-native-pager-view": "6.1.4",
    "react-native-progress": "bluesky-social/react-native-progress",
    "react-native-reanimated": "~2.14.4",
    "react-native-root-siblings": "^4.1.1",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^4.4.1",
    "react-native-screens": "^3.13.1",
    "react-native-splash-screen": "^3.3.0",
    "react-native-svg": "13.4.0",
    "react-native-url-polyfill": "^1.3.0",
    "react-native-uuid": "^2.0.1",
    "react-native-version-number": "^0.3.6",
    "react-native-web": "^0.18.11",
    "react-native-web-linear-gradient": "^1.1.2",
    "react-responsive": "^9.0.2",
    "rn-fetch-blob": "^0.12.0",
    "sentry-expo": "~6.1.0",
    "tippy.js": "^6.3.7",
    "tlds": "^1.234.0",
    "zod": "^3.20.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@atproto/pds": "^0.1.8",
    "@babel/core": "^7.20.0",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.20.0",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.20.0",
    "@did-plc/server": "^0.0.1",
    "@react-native-community/eslint-config": "^3.0.0",
    "@testing-library/jest-native": "^5.4.1",
    "@testing-library/react-native": "^11.5.2",
    "@tsconfig/react-native": "^2.0.3",
    "@types/he": "^1.1.2",
    "@types/jest": "^29.4.0",
    "@types/lodash.chunk": "^4.2.7",
    "@types/lodash.clonedeep": "^4.5.7",
    "@types/lodash.debounce": "^4.0.7",
    "@types/lodash.isequal": "^4.5.6",
    "@types/lodash.omit": "^4.5.7",
    "@types/lodash.samplesize": "^4.2.7",
    "@types/lodash.set": "^4.3.7",
    "@types/lodash.shuffle": "^4.2.7",
    "@types/react-avatar-editor": "^13.0.0",
    "@types/react-native": "^0.67.3",
    "@types/react-responsive": "^8.0.5",
    "@types/react-test-renderer": "^17.0.1",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.48.2",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^5.48.2",
    "babel-jest": "^29.4.2",
    "babel-loader": "^9.1.2",
    "babel-plugin-module-resolver": "^5.0.0",
    "babel-plugin-react-native-web": "^0.18.12",
    "detox": "^20.1.2",
    "eslint": "^8.19.0",
    "eslint-plugin-detox": "^1.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-ft-flow": "^2.0.3",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^5.5.0",
    "jest": "^29.4.3",
    "jest-expo": "^48.0.2",
    "jest-junit": "^15.0.0",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "^0.73.7",
    "prettier": "^2.8.3",
    "react-native-dotenv": "^3.3.1",
    "react-scripts": "^5.0.1",
    "react-test-renderer": "18.2.0",
    "ts-node": "^10.9.1",
    "typescript": "^4.4.4",
    "url-loader": "^4.1.1",
    "webpack": "^5.75.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^5.0.1",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^4.11.1"
  },
  "resolutions": {
    "@types/react": "^17"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "jest-expo/ios",
    "setupFilesAfterEnv": [
      "./jest/jestSetup.js",
      "@testing-library/jest-native/extend-expect"
    ],
    "moduleFileExtensions": [
      "ts",
      "tsx",
      "js",
      "jsx",
      "json",
      "node"
    ],
    "transformIgnorePatterns": [
      "node_modules/(?!((jest-)?react-native|@react-native(-community)?)|expo(nent)?|@expo(nent)?/.*|@expo-google-fonts/.*|react-navigation|@react-navigation/.*|@unimodules/.*|unimodules|sentry-expo|native-base|normalize-url|react-native-svg|@sentry/.*|sentry-expo)"
    ],
    "modulePathIgnorePatterns": [
      "__tests__/.*/__mocks__",
      "__e2e__/.*"
    ],
    "coveragePathIgnorePatterns": [
      "<rootDir>/node_modules/",
      "<rootDir>/src/platform",
      "<rootDir>/src/third-party",
      "<rootDir>/src/view/com/util",
      "<rootDir>/src/state/lib",
      "<rootDir>/__tests__/test-utils.js"
    ],
    "reporters": [
      "default",
      "jest-junit"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Could you please share your package.json?

Comment: Added `package.json`!

Comment: did this happen after upgrading to expo sdk 48?

Comment: I'm also noticing you don't have expo-modules installed. It is required if you want to use expo-image.
https://docs.expo.dev/bare/installing-expo-modules/

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here is [your issue](https://github.com/expo/eas-cli/issues/1841) and [here](https://github.com/expo/expo/pull/22491) the fix.
Basically you need to upgrade to expo-image@1.2.3

Comment: Yep, the versioning was the issue. When in doubt, upgrade. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you for the links - I've just been faced with the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try `yarn add expo-image`? I had the same issue and updating expo-image solved my issue.